# How to toggle a specific div in a mapped array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, react-hooks, mapping

I have a project where I'm mapping out an `array` with a like-button within the mapped out `div`.

This button should work only for the specific parent `div` - at the moment it toggles everything.

In my code, I tried to do it the long way around with a switch (it did not work, and also not good). I tried to look this up in various ways.

I think I need to work with `e.target`, but I'm not sure how to translate `e.target.value` to a state. For example - if I push button with value 5 (in div 5) I want the showDiv-state to take in the value (`showDiv{5}`) and be set to `true`.

What am I missing here?

```
    import { useState} from "react";
    import { BulletinBoard } from "./BulletinBoard";
    import PostLiked from "./PostLiked";

    const ReactPost = () => {
        const [showDiv, setShowDiv] = useState(false);
        const [showDiv2, setShowDiv2] = useState(false);
        const [showDiv3, setShowDiv3] = useState(false);
        const [showDiv4, setShowDiv4] = useState(false);
        const [showDiv5, setShowDiv5] = useState(false);
        const [likeButton, setLikeButton] = useState(true);
  
        const pickAndShow= (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const chosenItem = e.currentTarget.value; 

            switch(parseInt(chosenItem)){
            case 1: 
                console.log("Ett")
                setShowDiv1(true);
                setLikeButton(false);
            case 2:
                console.log("Två")
                setShowDiv2(true);
                setLikeButton(false);
                break;
            case 3:
                console.log("Tre")
                setShowDiv3(true);
                setLikeButton(false);
                break;
            case 4: 
                console.log("Fyra")
                setShowDiv4(true);
                setLikeButton(false);
                break;
            case 5:
                console.log("Fem")
                setShowDiv5(true);
                setLikeButton(false);
                break;
            default:
                console.log("Error")
            }
        }
    }

    return ( 
        <div className="grid">
        {BulletinBoard.map((item) => (
            <div className="grid-item"
                key={item.id}>
                <span className="row">
                    <p>Fråga #{item.id}</p>
                    <h2>{item.question}</h2>
                </span>
                <h3>{item.answer}</h3>
                <div 
                    className={`wrapper__${item.id}`}
                >
                    {!showDiv ? (
                    <button
                        className="likebutton"
                        value={item.id}
                        onClick={pickAndShow}
                    > </button> 
    
                    <div data-key={0 + item.id}>
                        {showDiv1 ? 
                            <PostLiked/>
                            enter code here
                        :null }
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>  
            ))}
        </div> 
        );
    }
 
    export default ReactPost;
```

EDIT: Here is a picture of what is happening now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arRt9.png)
When the checkbox is clicked, every `div` within the mapped `divs` change:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZel0.png)

Comment: can you please add how the UI looks ... an image or something that would be easy to understand on what you are trying to achieve or a [codesandbox](https://react.new) link ...

Comment: @KcH I added images now that might describe the error

Comment: so when like button is clicked it should not show the card ?

Comment: It should show the card - the button changes and there is the big thumb up. Basically, a div is revealed within the card that has the button. Now the div is revealed in every mapped div instead of the one that gets clicked. @KcH

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 5 `showDiv` state properties, you can have a single `shownDiv` property with a number value.

```
setShownDiv(parseInt(evt.currentTarget.value));
```